# Installing R odbc package on Databricks

Tags: r, odbc, databricks

In Databricks R notebook I am running the following line:

```
install.packages("odbc")
```

And I get back the following error:

```
Warning message:
Project requested R version '4.0.4' but '4.2.2' is currently being used 
ERROR: dependencies ‘bit64’, ‘blob’, ‘DBI’, ‘hms’, ‘Rcpp’, ‘rlang’ are not available for package ‘odbc’
* removing ‘/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/rEnv-55c7c155-1c55-423f-8ccf-43a8d86804b3/odbc’
Installing package into ‘/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/rEnv-55c7c155-1c55-423f-8ccf-43a8d86804b3’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/odbc_1.3.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 338480 bytes (330 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 330 KB

Warning in utils::install.packages(pkgs, ...) :
  installation of package ‘odbc’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpvruhjB/downloaded_packages’
```

I am guessing dependencies are missing, but

```
packageVersion("rlang")
```

returns:

```
‘1.0.6’
```

Why do I get error then?

P.S. It looks like installer also checks Project as well. I determines version used by Project 4.0.4

Comment: Have you tried installing the package on the cluster's Libraries under Cluster Configuration instead?

Comment: @Archeologist, ty, I need to try it